# Has Lego Box 5508 been discontinued?

Tags: building, sets

The Lego Deluxe Box 5508 seems to be out of stock everywhere in the UK. I was hoping to get this set for my kids for Christmas, but it is nowhere to be found. Has it been discontinued? Or do they think that sets that only build ONE thing will spark young imaginations? The 5508 box has bricks, roof tiles, windows, doors and wheels and opens up a world of possibilities. Shame I can't seem to find one!

Comment: A lot of LEGO sets will be out of stock in the run up to Christmas, particularly buckets/tubs of LEGO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible the set has been discontinued. Since its release in 2010 there have been many other Brick Buckets released under the ['Bricks and More'](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/Bricks-More-ByTheme?_requestid=836277) series.

For example; the [10663 Creative Chest](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10663-1) released in 2013 is available in a similar price range but is more limited to building vehicles (no doors, windows and roof tiles for buildings).

[image]

If your kids are more into buildings and there are no other Brick Buckets in stock you can suplement your LEGO collection by purchasing the [Doors & Windows](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/LEGO-Doors-Windows-6117?fromListing=listing) pack as well as the [Roof Tiles](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/LEGO-Roof-Tiles-6119?fromListing=listing) pack.